# Processor Detection Problem with Mathematica in Linux command-line

Tags: linux, scripting, command-line

Here is the problem, there are two ways to launch Mathematica in Linux:

1. Double click a notebook file in Desktop (GUI  mode).

It gives:

```
$ProcessorCount
(* 4 *)
```

`ParallelTable` is very efficient. (4 time faster than `Table`)

2. Use command “./bin/mathematica” in terminal, (or “./bin/math” , “./bin/wolfram” in command-line mode).

It gives:

```
$ProcessorCount  
(* 1 *)
```

`ParallelTable` then takes the same time as  `Table`.

What causes this difference? Does this mean that one can only access one processor within Mathematica when started in a Linux system terminal?

---------------solution

[image]

Comment: Oftentimes when I've seen similar issues in the past (specifically, `$ProcessorCount` returning incorrect values on Linux) it has been because of a incorrectly set environment variable. For example, `OMP_NUM_THREADS = 1`, or something. Any chance you may have something similar influencing things?

Comment: @user6014 , thanks for your suggestion. This problem were solved by reseting  `OMP_NUM_THREADS = 4`.

Comment: glad to hear :)

Comment: @user6014 Perhaps you could add that as an answer! I want to upvote you for it :)